# Gas cost tests: Sending a transaction to a new address is more expensive?

Tags: transactions, gas, ropsten, gas-estimate, address.transfer

A friend and I were thinking about transaction costs, is there any attached cost to send a transfer to a new address that has not been stored on chain before? So we started digging.

First off we called transfer to a new address and another one that has been used before, as expected the cost was 21000 for both of them.

New address: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xec05af75ec938aa1cc78612b13d8d2e3c8f4212f60173161450297c9a25ea5a3

Miner (used before) address:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x7fe1c8c699901923d89e07a9b66e7d952c67064bcc9d86bf84bad07cac2391b1

Then we tried to made the transfer from an SC, this is the function we are using:

`function test (address receiver) public payable {
        receiver.transfer(msg.value);
}`

Simple enough, we started testing, called the function to a new address:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x38dabd569350fa985e11f892f7175ad09a32a0c067b993f68152f34d7ca4dcb3

First surprising thing was the cost to execute this function, was 55356 gas, much higher then the 21000 we saw before, we called it again:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xa2d23ea51102cc98f92b6ef89ed452a5be0e0ebbc26c136fc43f9a5a67a99a52

To our surprise, now gas costs were 30356 much less than before, why??

We tried to call the function on a used address (that should be already stored on chain) to see if sending to a new address was the differential factor, we did it twice:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xf9eb2e6536db2ec933ac21fb5bd8c422b6ae3b811f4bd72be4a55e02a6aec227

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x4ef30764af81df4dc0dcc98bd4db5424c0c2bea99257df829b1c347a8764048f

And it costed 30356 in both.

Why does this happen, why sending ether to a new address from a SC costs over 50% more than sending to a used address?

Comment: You'd have to share the code for the smart contract. The gas cost of a `transfer` call shouldn't depend on whether the recipient has been the recipient of earlier transfers, but it's hard to give you an explanation without seeing the code.

Comment: (To clarify, I see the function you provided, but without the full code, it's hard to associate it with the bytecode and step through it.)

Comment: the rest of the contract shouldn't matter right? anyways MathematicalRain got it, I learnt something new today :) btw I'm a fan of your cte game, thanks for that!

Comment: In terms of gas cost, no, the rest of the contract shouldn't matter. I learned something new as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is true. If you read the Ethereum Yellow paper you can see in Appendix H that you have to pay extra gas if you send Ether to a new account.

This is to discourage addresses sending a load of transactions to new addresses, blowing up the chain size like that.

Comment: makes sense, but why doesn't it apply with a regular address.transfer(amount) those are always 21000 no matter if the address is new or not

Comment: FYI, I found this most accessible in Appendix G, the entry for Gnewaccount. The gas cost is 25000 for a "CALL or SUICIDE operation which creates a new account."

Comment: @smarx You are correct, 25000 is the exact difference and a new account has been created. 
Digging some more I found this cost was set because of a gas calculation bug exploited at around block 2100000, still don't know why this doesn't apply for regular address.transfer